# Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field Django

Tags: django

I'm totally new to Django. I've read over the docs, and I've looked up things on here, but there's not much. I'm basically trying to having profiles display on a page that I've already created. I'm using a custom user model.

And the thing is, I was suggested to simply take out 'user' in 'user=request.user, but problem is if I do that, than I get 'Profile' is not iterable.

**Error at line `description = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description`:**

```
FieldError at /mingle/
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, description, email, given_vote, id, is_active, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, matches, password, photo, username, uservote
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/mingle/
Django Version: 2.2.3
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:    
Cannot resolve keyword 'user' into field. Choices are: date_joined, description, email, given_vote, id, is_active, is_admin, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, logentry, matches, password, photo, username, uservote
Exception Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py in names_to_path, line 1420
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
Python Version: 3.7.3
Python Path:    
['/Users/papichulo/Documents/DatingAppCustom',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python37.zip',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload',
 '/Users/papichulo/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages',
 '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages']
Server time:    Sun, 5 Apr 2020 19:20:01 +0000
```

**mingle.html**

```
{% extends "dating_app/base.html" %}
{% load bootstrap4 %}


{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    {% if user %}
        <div class="container content is-child box column is-4 is-offset-4">
            <img src="{{ profile.photo.url  }}">
            <p style="font-size: 25px">{{profile}}</p>

            <b>Bio:</b>
            <p>{{profile.description}}</p>

        </div>
    {% else %}
        <p>Wait for more people to join!</p>
        <p>Help us get more user. Share this link to your friends! <a href="http://localhost:8000/">http://localhost:8000/</a></p>
  {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```
def mingle(request):




    try:
        user = (Profile.objects.exclude(id=request.user.id).exclude(uservote__voter=request.user).order_by('?')[0])
    except IndexError:
        user = None
        print(Profile.username)
    try:

        description = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description
    except Profile.DoesNotExist:
        create = Profile.objects.get_or_create(user = request.user)
        return redirect('profile')

    match = models.Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).matches.all()
    context = dict(user = user, match = match)  
    return render(request, 'dating_app/mingle.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
class ProfileManager(BaseUserManager):



    def create_user(self, username, email,description,photo, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("You must creat an email")
        if not username:
            raise ValueError("You must create a username!")
        if not description:
            raise ValueError("You must write a description")
        if not photo:
            raise ValueError("You must upload a photo")

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                username = username, 
                description= description,
                photo= photo,

            )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user 


    def create_superuser(self, username, email,description,photo, password):
        user = self.create_user(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                password=password,
                username=username,
                description=description,
                photo=photo,

            )

        user.is_admin=True
        user.is_staff=True
        user.is_superuser=True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user




class Profile(AbstractBaseUser):

    class Meta:
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'


    email                       = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email")
    username                    = models.CharField(max_length=30, unique=True)
    date_joined                 = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='date joined', auto_now_add=True)
    last_login                  = models.DateTimeField(verbose_name='last login', auto_now=True)
    is_admin                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active                   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff                    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser                = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    #what I added
    description                 = models.TextField()
    photo                       = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_photo',blank=False, height_field=None, width_field=None, max_length=100)
    matches                     = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='+', blank=True)



    USERNAME_FIELD = 'username'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['description','photo','email']


    objects = ProfileManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.username


    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin


    def has_module_perms(self,app_label):
        return True



class UserVote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    voter = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name='given_vote', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('user', 'voter'))
```

Comment: Well your profile indeed does not contain a `user` field, hence `Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)` queries can indeed not work.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem So then how would I query the profile objects? I tried replacing user with 'profile' given that's my user model now and setting.auth links to 'Profile' , but that didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set `AUTH_USER_MODEL` in your settings.py to point to your custom `Profile` model?  If so, `request.user` will already be the user that you're trying to filter for.

You can change:

```
description = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user).description
```

To:

```
description = request.user.description
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that was exactly what I needed! Yes, I had indeed changed my AUTH_USER_MODEL to point to my custom Profile model. So basically,  since my profile model was the only user model available, it was already looking for it to begin with, right?

Comment: Yes when you changed your AUTH_USER_MODEL in your settings.py Django started referencing that model everywhere for users

Comment: Ok got it. I am having a related problem now... so while it does go through to my template without any errors, the information is not showing up. All I get is the words 'bio' being printed without the objects bio. No picture either. I am trying to get a random profile to show up and then I can add buttons so a user can like or dislike a profile.I am not sure why this is happening, but I don't believe I am doing anything wrong in the template. I think something in my logic is incorrect. I will edit my question and add the template so you can take a look at it.

Comment: In fact, now every time I go to mingle.html and hit the link, the user changes. As in, there is a different logged in user. The display on the right that shows which user is logged in changes. So I assume there's something wrong